# SQL report returns dash when there is no match

Tags: sql

I have a list of branches and when there is no branch the result is returned as a dash. I've tried doing a case when like so:

```
CASE Table.column
WHEN '-' THEN 'Global'
ELSE Table.column
END
```

This does nothing. I tried:

```
CASE Table.column
WHEN NULL THEN 'Global
ELSE Table.column
END
```

This also did nothing. Any thoughts? The table that the branch data comes from has no row with a dash in it.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE Table.column
WHEN NULL THEN 'Global'
ELSE Table.column
END
```

This means the same as

```
CASE
WHEN Table.column = NULL THEN 'Global'
ELSE Table.column
END
```

but Table.column won't ever compare equal to NULL, because nothing compares equal to NULL. Use IS NULL instead:

```
CASE
WHEN Table.column IS NULL THEN 'Global'
ELSE Table.column
END
```

Or shorter, if your database supports it:

```
COALESCE(Table.column, 'Global')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I'm a little confused. I was trying IS NULL and getting errors around the 'IS' part. This is how I coded mine: CASE Organisation.txtDescription
WHEN IS NULL THEN 'Global'
ELSE Organisation.txtDescription 
END

Comment: CASE has two possible syntaxes: CASE (value) WHEN (value1) THEN ... WHEN (value2) THEN ... ELSE ... END, or CASE WHEN (boolean1) THEN ... WHEN (boolean2) THEN ... ELSE ... END. The first syntax always compares as if using =, if you want a different comparison (and you do here), you need the second syntax, and the second syntax has nothing between CASE and WHEN.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN Table.colmun = '-' THEN 'Global' ELSE Table.column END
```

Comment: @user1076439 I'm sorry, I forgot the 'END' I recommend the solution of hvd. Its more precise.